# How to convert value into radian in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, math, trigonometry

Iam trying to convert value into sin, cos, tan, arctan in python.

could somebody help me to write a function in python to convert -1/2 into Sin(-Pi/6)

Thanks alot

Comment: ```print(math.radians(-1/2))```?

Comment: Thanks, but i want the result is kind of -1/2 = Sin(-Pi/6)

Answer (score 1):

You need inverse trigonometric functions - `atan, asin, acos`.

For example,

```
import math

t = -0.5
an = math.asin(t)
print(an)  # in radians
print("Sin(Pi*{}".format(an / math.pi)) 
if an:
    print("Sin(Pi/{}".format(math.pi / an))
```

But note that these functions are "multi-valued" (don't know exact English term), so for example you may expect `-3*Pi/4`  for atan of `1.0`, but get main value `Pi/4`

Answer (score 0):

Is that mean you want to print sin(-Pi/6) with input -1/2 ?

Comment: Yes, that what i mean